# Intrabar-only actions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I was wondering if I can trigger an action only based on current bar, and not the “just closed” one. I flagged the “recalculate on every tick” and it works intrabar, but it also triggers once bar is closed, if the previous bar meets the conditions I set. This because `close` also refers to prev bar closing price. Is there a way to limit the analysis to current bar (intrabar only)?

Comment: pls share code example that you have problems with. `recalculate on every tick` allows to calculate strategy on every tick, including current bar close. it not refers to prev bar closing price, unless you program it to.

Comment: AFAIK 'close' refers also to previous bar closing price once the new bar is created (barstate.isnew). Thence if you have a strategy that performs actions based on that, it will execute also upon new bar creation if the condition is still met.
For now I solved it using 'if barstate.islast
     and barstate.isrealtime
     and barstate.isconfirmed == false' as additional conditions.

Now I need the action to be executed only once per bar. :)

Comment: No, `close` will refer to current bar unless you do `close[1]` which in that case would refer to the previous bar.

Comment: When it is a new bar (not closed), `close` will refer to its current price.